# need help with a Two-Part Trigger.new trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, class

I could really use some assistance with my trigger/class/test class below.

Background:  Our SFDC is integrated via WDSL with our SAP installation.  SAP is where our Sales Orders (Opportunities and Opportunity Line Items) are created.  SAP will send the information over to SFDC and create the Opportunity with the associated products and Pricebook that is used.

Our Pricebooks are set up so they are 3 tier pricing by region (Master, National, Regional).

What I am trying to do is this:
At the OpportunityLineItem level, I want to populate the 3 different prices into 3 separate fields for that Opportunity, based on the pricebook's region.

example:
Product A in:
NorthAmerica-Master is $11.11
NorthAmerica-National is $22.22
NorthAmerica-Regional is $33.33

The Opportunity created in SFDC will be a NorthAmerica-National order so I'm looking to get something like this at the OpportunityLineItem level:

Product A
SalesPrice $15.55
XExpress Master Price $11.11
XExpress National Price $22.22
XExpress Regional Price $33.33

The motivator for this is to improve our commissioning system's accuracy.

I believe the problem I'm running into is related to when the objects are created in the system.  I'm using a Before Insert, which I think is wrong because it can't determine the Opportunity Id, that I need to get to the Account so I can pull the Pricebook Region's root (e.g. 'NorthAmerica').  I would then use that root to build 3 queries to get the products pricing in each of those pricebooks.  The root changes from customer to customer, based on where they are globally.

I saw another person post something about a two part trigger.new, but I've read through the example code several times & it feels like I'm doing something very similar, but it's like an After Insert is what's needed...but then the record is read only.

For me, it's completely OK for this to run/update after the record is created, but the values in these pricing fields shouldn't change after the record is created.  If there's an update to the values in one of the 3 pricebooks (in the future), the old pricing that's written to these 3 fields should not change.

Any help is greatly appreciated:
**TRIGGER CODE:**

```
trigger OpportunityLineTrigger2 on OpportunityLineItem (Before insert) {
OpportunityActions2.updateXactlyPrices(trigger.new, trigger.isInsert, trigger.isBefore);
}
```

**CLASS CODE:**

```
    public class OpportunityActions2 {

       //Copy Master, National and Regional Price Book’s Unit Price in all Opportunity Line Item
        public static void  updateXactlyPrices(List<OpportunityLineItem> newOppProds, Boolean isInsert, Boolean isBefore) {

        Set<Id> productIDs= new set<Id>();
        Set<Id> Opty = new set<Id>();

        List<PricebookEntry> MasterpricebookEntry = new List<PricebookEntry >();
        List<PricebookEntry> NationalpricebookEntry = new List<PricebookEntry >();
        List<PricebookEntry> RegionalpricebookEntry = new List<PricebookEntry >();


        Id MasterPriceBookId;
        Id NationalPriceBookId;
        Id RegionalPriceBookId;
        Id StandardPriceBookId;
        String PBNameMaster;
        String PBNameNational;
        String PBNameRegional;
        String PBRoot;


        for(OpportunityLineItem opp : newOppProds){
            productIDs.add(opp.ProductID__c);
            Opty.add(opp.OpportunityId); //add the opportunity ID to get the pricebook info
        }

              String PricebookRoot = [SELECT Account.XExpress_Pricebook_Root__c from Opportunity where Id=:Opty limit 1].Account.XExpress_Pricebook_Root__c;

System.debug('The Opportunity ID is: ' + Opty);
System.debug('The productIDs is: ' + productIDs);
System.debug('The PricebookRoot is: ' + PricebookRoot);


        PBNameMaster=PricebookRoot+'-Master';
        PBNameNational=PricebookRoot+'-National';
        PBNameRegional=PricebookRoot+'-Regional';



System.debug('The Master PB is: ' + PBNameMaster);
System.debug('The National PB is: ' + PBNameNational);
System.debug('The Regional is: ' + PBNameRegional);

        MasterPriceBookId = [select Id, Name from PriceBook2 Where name =:PBNameMaster].Id;
        NationalPriceBookId = [select Id, Name from PriceBook2 Where name =:PBNameNational].Id;
        RegionalPriceBookId = [select Id, Name from PriceBook2 Where name =:PBNameRegional].Id;

System.debug('The Master PB ID is: ' + MasterPriceBookId);
System.debug('The National PB ID is: ' + NationalPriceBookId);
System.debug('The Regional ID is: ' + RegionalPriceBookId);

        MasterpricebookEntry = [SELECT Id,Name,Pricebook2Id,Product2Id,UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id =:MasterPriceBookId and Product2Id in : productIDs];        
        NationalpricebookEntry = [SELECT Id,Name,Pricebook2Id,Product2Id,UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id =:NationalPriceBookId and Product2Id in : productIDs];        
        RegionalpricebookEntry = [SELECT Id,Name,Pricebook2Id,Product2Id,UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntry where Pricebook2Id =:RegionalPriceBookId and Product2Id in : productIDs];        

System.debug('The Master PB Entry is: ' + MasterpricebookEntry);
System.debug('The National Entry ID is: ' + NationalpricebookEntry);
System.debug('The Regional Entry is: ' + RegionalpricebookEntry);



        for(OpportunityLineItem ol : newOppProds){
            for(PricebookEntry pb : MasterpricebookEntry){

                if(ol.ProductID__c == pb.Product2Id) {
                    ol.XExpress_Master_Price__c = pb.UnitPrice;                    
                }   
            }            
            for(PricebookEntry pb : NationalpricebookEntry){

                if(ol.ProductID__c == pb.Product2Id) {
                    ol.XExpress_National_Price__c = pb.UnitPrice;                    
                }   
            }            
            for(PricebookEntry pb : RegionalpricebookEntry){

                if(ol.ProductID__c == pb.Product2Id) {
                    ol.XExpress_Regional_Price__c = pb.UnitPrice;                    
                    ol.Standard_Price__c = pb.UnitPrice;                    
                }   
            }            
        }              

        }
}
```

**TEST CLASS CODE:**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData = true)
private class OpportunityActions_Test2
{
    static testMethod void OpportunityActions_Method1()
    {

        Product2 prodRec = new product2();
        prodRec.name='test prod21';
        prodRec.family='level 3';
        prodRec.IsActive = true;
        prodRec.Unit_Price__c = 21.21;
        insert prodRec; 

        Pricebook2 Price = new Pricebook2();
        Price.Name = 'My Test ABCXYZ Price List';
        Price.IsActive = true;
        Price.XExpress_Pricebook_Root__c='NorthAmerica';
        insert Price;

        Id stdPriceBookId = [Select Id from PriceBook2 where isStandard = true].Id;
        Id MasterPBId = [Select Id from PriceBook2 where Name = 'NorthAmerica-Master'].Id;
        Id NationalPBId = [Select Id from PriceBook2 where Name = 'NorthAmerica-National'].Id;
        Id RegionalPBId = [Select Id from PriceBook2 where Name = 'NorthAmerica-Regional'].Id;

//a standard price for the created product needs to be entered        
        PricebookEntry PBEntry1 = new PricebookEntry();
        PBEntry1.Pricebook2Id = stdPriceBookId;
        PBEntry1.Product2Id= prodRec.id;
        PBEntry1.UnitPrice = prodRec.Unit_Price__c +2;
        PBEntry1.Isactive=True;    
        PBEntry1.UseStandardPrice = false;
        insert PBEntry1;

//a Master price for the created product needs to be entered        
        PricebookEntry PBEntry2 = new PricebookEntry();
        PBEntry2.Pricebook2Id = MasterPBId;
        PBEntry2.Product2Id= prodRec.id;
        PBEntry2.UnitPrice = prodRec.Unit_Price__c +2;
        PBEntry2.Isactive=True;    
        PBEntry2.UseStandardPrice = false;
        insert PBEntry2;
//a National price for the created product needs to be entered        
        PricebookEntry PBEntry3 = new PricebookEntry();
        PBEntry3.Pricebook2Id = NationalPBId;
        PBEntry3.Product2Id= prodRec.id;
        PBEntry3.UnitPrice = prodRec.Unit_Price__c +12;
        PBEntry3.Isactive=True;    
        PBEntry3.UseStandardPrice = false;
        insert PBEntry3;
//a Regional price for the created product needs to be entered        
        PricebookEntry PBEntry4 = new PricebookEntry();
        PBEntry4.Pricebook2Id = RegionalPBId;
        PBEntry4.Product2Id= prodRec.id; ';
        PBEntry4.UnitPrice = prodRec.Unit_Price__c +22;
        PBEntry4.Isactive=True;    
        PBEntry4.UseStandardPrice = false;
        insert PBEntry4;


        PricebookEntry PBEntry5 = new PricebookEntry();
        PBEntry5.Pricebook2Id = Price.id;
        PBEntry5.Product2Id= prodRec.id; ;
        PBEntry5.UnitPrice = prodRec.Unit_Price__c ;
        PBEntry5.Isactive=True;    
        PBEntry5.UseStandardPrice = false;
        insert PBEntry5;

        user u = [select id,User_Region__c,SAP_User__c from user where profile.name = 'System Administrator' and isActive = true limit 1];

        Account acc= new Account();
        acc.Name = 'TestAcct1';
        acc.Price_Book__c = Price.id;
        acc.Distributor_Type__c = 'Master Distributor';
        acc.opportunity_Owner__c = u.id;
        acc.Distributor_Owner__c = u.id;
        acc.BillingCity='Crown Point';
        acc.BillingState='IN';
        acc.BillingPostalCode='46307';
        acc.BillingCountry='US';
        acc.Billing_Country_Code__c='US - UNITED STATES';
        acc.SAP_Customer_Number__c = '12345';
        insert acc;

        contact c = new contact(lastname = 'Satriani', accountid = acc.id);
        insert c;
        system.runAs(u) {

        Id RTId = [select id from RecordType where sObjectType=:'Opportunity' and IsActive=:true and name=:'Distribution'].id;        

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
        opp.RecordTypeId =RTId;
        opp.Name = 'Test Opp';
        opp.AccountId = acc.id;
        opp.CloseDate = System.today();
        opp.Sales_Order_Date__c=System.today();
        opp.StageName = 'Order Created';
        opp.Order_Type__c = 'Distributor Stock';
        opp.Region__c = 'Canada';
        opp.SAP_Customer_Number__c = '414141';
        insert opp; 

        OpportunityLineItem opplineitem1 =  new OpportunityLineItem();
        opplineitem1.OpportunityId = opp.id;
        opplineitem1.PricebookEntryId=PBEntry1.Id;
        opplineitem1.UnitPrice= 17.77;
        opplineitem1.First_Commit_Date__c = system.today();
        opplineitem1.Quantity = 41;
        opplineitem1.Current_Schedule_Date__c = System.today();
        opplineitem1.SFDC_Unique_Number__c  = 7877;
        opplineitem1.Standard_Price__c = 23.95;
        insert opplineitem1;
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: Why not add a formula on the oli that pulls the account field over

Comment: (1) before insert on OLI definitely will know `OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId` as that is a required field to insert an OLI; and (2) - don't use `seealldata=true` - mock everything in testmethod, including custom settings.  Standard PricebookId is available from `Test.getStandardPricebookId()`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion cropredy....I will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: cropredy-
I was able to use the test.getstandardpricebookid() and that works fine.  However when I tried removing the seealldata=true, none of the other pricebook Id assignments (for the custom pricebook IDs) were called.  all queries return null / empty.  Are you suggesting that I build all 3 custom pricebooks within the test class & ignore the query calls?  When this rolls to production, how would I really know if the query calls are actually working?  Just a qualifier on this comment...I've been under the weather lately & has been hard to conceptualize this.